# What is needed to upgrade client for Crystal Reports from VS 2005 to VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, .net-3.5, crystal-reports

I am upgrading an application that was originally written in VS 2005 (.NET 3.0) and now I am upgrading that application to VS 2008 (.NET 3.5).  I have Crystal .rpt files that I have created in VS 2005.  The application is a Windows Forms app. What is needed to run the applications on the client for Crystal?  Is there a installation I need to run or will all the necessary files be included in the application?  I am trying to figure out what I need to do to upgrade the reports, if anything for the developers and for the clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Crystal Report executable changed for 3.5.  Aside from migrating your codebase from .NET 2.0 to 3.5, nothing else needs to change.

Comment: So are you saying there is no installation that needs to run on the client machines?

Comment: Incorrect - the .NET Crystal Report executable needs to be deployed to workstations, same as when done with .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built-in reports that come with VS 2005, you should be fine. If you check the references for the Crystal controls, you will see that VS 2008 still uses the version 10 reports. But if you are using the full Crystal Reports XI R2, then you should read [this](https://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/oss_notes_boj/sdn_oss_boj_dev/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes%7B6163636573733d36393736354636443646363436353344333933393338323636393736354637333631373036453646373436353733354636453735364436323635373233443330333033303331333233303334333833373337%7D.do)